# Visual Studio 2015 community won't install Windows SDK

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, visual-studio-2015

[Image describing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiuM2.png)
Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition won't go passed Windows Software Development Kit on the install. The dots however are still moving. I have installed it several times, both ISO and Web Installer. I also tried the 2013 version but the same outcome occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, in my case I had the ISO so what you do is restart your computer and when vs 2015 starts installing, you find the file that I can't find.in your extracted ISO (extract using 7zip) then keep doing that for every other file